# How to implement accessibility for ALAsset photos on iOS

Tags: ios, accessibility, exif, alassetslibrary, voiceover

I wrote a custom image picker based on `ALAssetsLibrary`, everything works fine but `VoiceOver`, every photo are only representing as "Button", I think that is not good.

So I checked the `Photo` app that built in iOS, `VoiceOver` spoke following information for each photo:

1. It's `photo` or `video` or `screenshot` etc.
2. It's `portrait` or `landscape`.
3. The `creation date` of it.
4. It's `sharp` or `blurry`.
5. It's `bright` or `dark`.

I think I can get the *first three* from `ALAsset`'s properties, which is

1. `ALAssetPropertyType`
2. `ALAssetPropertyOrientation`
3. `ALAssetPropertyDate`

But how about **sharpness** and **brightness**? Can I get them from image Metadata or derive them out?

**Update:**

In the Photo's EXIF metadata:

1. brightness is available with photos taken directly from camera, but photos saved from web or captured from screen always returns nil value.
2. sharpness is always nil in the exif, from the document, sharpness value is "The sharpness applied to the image", so I think it is used by image-processing app (such as Aperture)

But `Photos.app` always have right brightness and sharpness values for any kind of photo, is it possible to do this by ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get values using `EXIF` metadata.

All the keys are refferenced in **Apple's Docs** [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/EXIF_Dictionary_Keys)

Here I wrote an example:

```
NSDictionary *allMetadata = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];

NSDictionary *exif = [allMetadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
```

and than get `sharpness` and `brightness`

```
NSNumber *sharpness = [exif objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifSharpness];
NSNumber *brightness = [exif objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifBrightnessValue];
```

Comment: I found two problems, 1. brightness is available with photos taken directly from camera, but photos saved from web or captured from screen always returns nil value. 2. sharpness is always nil in the exif, from the document, sharpness value is "The sharpness applied to the image", so I think it is used by image-processing app (such as Aperture)? those two problem not occurs in Photos.app.

Comment: And don't forget to add `#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`